# Catch Textbox event from another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

I have an event in my Form:

```
 public void filterByType_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dSearch = new D_Search(this);
        dSearch.filterD(); }
```

which calls a function in another class. What I want to do is that I want to notice in my class which Textbox was altered and do something. So there are multiple functions like the one above and they all call the "filterD()" function in my DSearch class. I tried

```
if (sender == form1.filterByType_TextChanged)
        { sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM" } //SQL Statement
        }

     datTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, 
        connection);
        sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);

        form1.setDataGrid = datTable;
```

but he can't find "sender" I also tried to create a new Button within the function in my Form and pass it but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

**In form 1**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var dSearch = new D_Search(this);
     MessageBox.Show(dSearch.filterD(sender));
}
```

**D_Search class**

```
public class D_Search
{
    Form1 frm = null;

    public D_Search(Form1 frm1)
    {
        frm = frm1;
    }

    public string filterD(object sender)
    {
        string val = String.Empty;
        if (sender == frm.textBox1)
        {
            val = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

also if you want to access `filterByType_TextChanged` textbox in other class then change its modifier property to `Internal`

Comment: not working. dSearch.filterD() is the function I call over the event in the form. He still doesn't know sender.

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException because when he goes out of the if statement I have "datTable = new DataTable()" and "sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);" written and I get the Exception at the SqlAdapter Statement

Comment: That is a different thing. I believe I have answered your question, if Yes then please mark this as answer. And for the other error post a new question.

Comment: Please post exact code do not write it. The code you posted has syntax errors.

Comment: I posted it. I just didn't post the SQL code completely. - ok now it should work